# How do I delete files by counting how many times the prefix is used?

Tags: shell, csv, file, delete-file

Let's say I have a folder such as:

```
Name1_1542.csv
Name1_1543.csv
Name1_1544.csv
...

Name2_1543.csv
Name2_1544.csv
Name2_1545.csv
...

Name3_1490.csv
Name3_1491.csv
Name3_1492.csv
...
```

The first part `Namex` is different for each batch of files.
I want to count how many times each `Namex` prefix is repeated on a folder and delete all the files starting with the prefixes for which result is less than 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I would if I even knew where to start, but I don't, hence I'm asking this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'for (<Name*.csv>) { my @F = split /_/; push @{$files{$F[0]}}, $_ }
         for (values %files) { unlink @$_ if @$_ < 10 }'
```